# how do I change the cursor style in Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublimetext3

At some point my cursor changed from a vertical bar to an underbar. I must have pressed some magic combination of keys. Any idea how to change it back?

Answer (score 105, accepted):

Hit <kbd>Insert</kbd> That'll change it back. You might have noticed that if you went back on code and typed some you'd be overwriting instead of inserting.

Comment: I'll go stand in the corner.

Comment: where is `insert` key on Mac? Especially on Mac laptops with limited keyboard.

Comment: You can use the **Shift + 0** combination too. The zero must be from numeric keypad.

Comment: `Option + Command + o` worked for me.

Answer (score 57):

On mac OS, to toggle between vertical and horizontal cursor in SublimeText 3:

<kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>option</kbd> + <kbd>o</kbd>

Answer (score 4):

in my case it changed on pressing key `fn+insert`

in SublimeText 3 and windows 10

Answer (score 3):

In Windows PC You can simply press **insert** or **fn+0** (0 on numpad) or **fn + delete** or insert.

Answer (score 2):

On MacOS, where there's no <kbd>insert</kbd> key, <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> may be the best approach (it imitates <kbd>insert</kbd>).

Answer (score 2):

'**Shift+Ins**' in the Numpad worked for me in Genie text editor. It was quite disturbing to see the code overwritten instead of inserting.

Answer (score 1):

Stuff like this happens a lot in Sublime to me. To answer your question `<Insert>` changes it back. Often I'll hit some keys and end up in full screen mode which is never fun.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows:
Fn + Insert. In some keyboards separate insert is not given.They can use Fn + prt sc

Answer (score 0):

You can go to Preferences -> Settings and in a right panel add your custom preferences.
In my case I added this:
"caret_extra_top": 1,
"caret_extra_bottom": 1,
"caret_extra_width": 4,
.[image]

Answer (score 0):

**All cursor ('caret') settings are here:**

[image: Preferences]

---

[image: Caret options]

Answer (score -1):

first One off the numlock Then next press the 0 ( zero ) key