# Changing the default cursor in sublime text3 - windows10

Tags: windows, insert, cursor, key, sublimetext3

I am relatively new user of sublime so please consider helping me out,
I am aware that pressing the "insert" key in windows changes sublime into the overwrite mode
(with a underbar), and pressing "insert" again reverts it back to the "append" mode, and the vertical line cursor, discused [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19259852/how-do-i-change-the-cursor-style-in-sublime-text-3)
My question - is there a way of changing the default cursor (append mode) to the underbar.
Any help is appreciated!
Thanks!
Please excuse me for any gramatical errors.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to modify the cursor, but it comes with a catch. The feature is only available in the Sublime Text "4" alpha builds, which you can only run if you're a registered user and willing to run alpha-level software, which means occasional random crashes and features not working right as the bugs get ironed out. You're also committing to upgrading to each new build as it's released and reporting issues back to the dev team. If you're interested, start at the Sublime Discord server [here](https://discord.com/channels/280102180189634562/280102180189634562). The new builds are posted in #announcements.

You say you're a relatively new user, so I would not recommend running the alpha builds at this time, especially if it's just for this one feature.